# AJAX: Cannot pass object through context parameter into ajaxSuccess function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Any idea why i cant pass context into the `ajaxSuccess` function? I also tried doing it through the proxy method but it doesn't seem to work.

Snippet from my test.js:

```
$('a.ajax-nav').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: event.currentTarget.href,
    context: {foo: 'bar'}
  });
});
```

And then the [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/):

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  console.log(foo.bar);
});
```

I'm using ajaxSuccess to have a global event that should happen on all successfully ajax requests.

Comment: try `this.foo` will solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are passing it as the context, you should be able to access the object via the `settings` object.

Looks like the ajaxSuccess is not called with the context parameter.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    console.log(settings.context.foo);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tQnvw/)

Comment: Thanks! noticed i could also pass this and retrieve it through settings.context.